# PJS.Bootstrap Orchard Theme Settings

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to use the PJS.Bootstrap Theme in Orchard.  After I've enabled the module I can see a "Theme-Bootstrap" menu option under Settings on the Dashboard.  When I click that menu item, all I see is Settings page with just a "Save" button and nothing else.

I'm expecting to see something where I can switch between different CSS styles.  When I look at the source for the Theme I'm seeing items like cosmo, cyborg, darkly, etc.

Is there something else I need to do to get the PJS.Bootstrap Theme to show Settings?  I'm using Orchard v.1.10.1

Thanks!

Comment: I'd check the error log first. Also where did you get the theme from? Do you have a link?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the logs.  I got the theme at http://gallery.orchardproject.net/Packages/Orchard.Theme.PJS.Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to upgrade the module to .NET 4.5.2, it is currently at 4.5.1. So if you add the theme to your themes folder and add it in Visual Studio, then right click the project and select Properties, here you can change the .NET version. You'll probably also need to remove the references to JetBrains in the BootstrapThemeSettingsPartHandler.cs class.

Comment: The .NET version was already at 4.5.2.  I ran into that issue earlier.  I was getting errors when it was at 4.5.1.  I tried commenting out the JetBrains reference.  I also had to comment out [UsedImplicity].  I then built and ran.  The Settings page is still empty.  I also checked the logs again.  I didn't see any errors.  Anything to try?

Comment: Sorry I cant think of anything. It works fine for me. Things to try: start with a clean installation, debug the settings controller, check another template is not overriding the one sent by bootstrap theme

Comment: OK.  I looked around the project and I can't seem to find the settings controller.  What's the path and filename?

Comment: The controller is in Orchard.Core.Settings.Controllers, it is a generic controller used for all settings. It is passed a group id and builds the settings for that group id

Comment: OK, I see if that helps.  Thanks

Comment: I've got a fork of the theme that works (and shows the settings page) with 1.10.x at https://github.com/robertwray/PJS.Bootstrap